# How can I delete everything in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Searching for resources in AWS Console is a hell task. This asnwer helped me to find out used resources from which I do not recognize many (e.g. regions I have never used). Fortunatelly the bill is still 0. But I rather want to clean up the table. Deleting one resource by one is very tedious and takes lots of time. Is there some easy way (except shutting down the account) how to remove all used resources?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke). It is a tool to help remove all resources in an AWS account.

The resources listed in the screenshot are related to the default VPC which is automatically created for each region on account creation. IMHO it is ok to keep those.